# How to use findOne properly in MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. After following a tutorial, I have created a database (say test) followed by a collection to it say (names) and have inserted a data to that.

Now when I am performing a FindOne() on the collection, I am getting an error

```
C:\Users\abc>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
connecting to: test
> use test
switched to db test
> show collections
names
> test.names.findOne();
2016-03-20T09:16:30.366+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: test is not de
fined :
@(shell):1:1

>
```

What is the mistake that I am doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of accessing the db with the name, use db

```
db.names.findOne()
```